# How to reload module only

Tags: angular, webpack, livereload, hot-module-replacement

I have tried different Hot Module Replacement and different thing, but it is my understanding that there is no way to recompile just the small changes as it will always compile the entire application. This means for each change I have to wait about 10 seconds.

Is there any current available solution for a livereload / hot reload so it would quickly get only the relevant changes?

Comment: Have you tried the --hmr option of the ng serve command ? https://angular.io/cli/serve

Comment: I have. Unfortunately as of right now they don't actually support hot module replacement properly. It always compiles all application modules for each change. The end result is pretty much the same as ng build --watch.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17324#issuecomment-608036011